# How to set 6 record per page in matrix when i rendering reports in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I have 239 records and I want 6 records per matrix so I kept matrix inside list and apply a group on expression like CEILING(Row Number(Nothing)/6)
So its working fine but at the end of rendering all records its skipping last 5 records its only showing 234 records even when I need all 239 records means last matrix should contain 5 records also.

Comment: I am unable to recreate this problem in SSRS 2008 R2 (the final group contains 5 records), can you confirm the version of SSRS/VS you are using?

Comment: Hi Jonnus- yes my reporting server is 2012 but i don't think so its version problem. it's a logical problem and right not my am not able to hit it.